# Using ezSQL functions from another file

Tags: php, mysql, ezsql

Im using ezSQL in my PHP application and I have a problem.

This is my structure

**config.php code:**

```
include_once "ez_sql_core.php";
include_once "ez_sql_mysql.php";
$db = new ezSQL_mysql('myuser','mypass','mydb','localhost');
```

**index.php code:**

```
include('includes/config.php');
include('includes/functions.php');

echo prueba();
```

**functions.php code:**

```
function prueba()
{
    $users = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM users");

    foreach ( $users as $user )
    {
        echo $user->user;
    }
}
```

But i get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object
>   in /web/htdocs/mydomain/includes/functions.php on line
>   7

How can I fix it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the `$db` variable from the global table into your function's local variable table:

```
function prueba()
{
    global $db;
```

You get the error because the `$db` object was not available in your function. `var_dump($db);` is your friend in such cases.